# How can i redirect the user to a 'section' on an html page from another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor, sections

1. I have a main webpage - index.html which has a section "#features".
2. I have a back button on another webpage subpage.html which redirects the user to
   the index.html page ( I have used onclick="document.location =
   index.html" to redirect the user to index.html page)

I want to redirect the user to the section "#features" on the index.html page when the user clicks on the back button on the subpage.html page.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through an internal page anchor. Try this:

in subpage.html

```
window.location.href= "index.html#features";
```

in index.html

```
<a id="features">row 15 data here.</a>
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/cngogo7p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem.
Simply wrap the button with an `a` tag with 
`href="/index.html#feature"`.
If both pages are in the same directory, use `href="./index.html#feature"`

Comment: Hey, this suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you. But isnt it true that you cannot put a div element inside an anchor tag?

Comment: No. You can put a `div` element inside an anchor tag. As far as I remember, you can put almost every element inside an anchor tag.

Comment: Yup, just as long as the anchor tag has a name or id on it (name or id would have to be features in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`scrollIntoView`** function in javascript. Checkout the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).